# Laravel 5.1 - Make a string with variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

i have this code in my index of products of my ecommerce.

```
<img src="{{ url('shop',['category' => $product->category->name,'gender' => $product->gender->name,'slug'=> $product->project->slug ])}}" title="{{$product->name}}" alt="">
```

It create a link like this:

> http://localhost:8000/shop/t-shirt/men/some-slug-product

i would like create like this:

> http://localhost:8000/shop/t-shirt,men,some-slug-product

So i can create image and save the title image with variables separated by comma.

I tryed different option but it doesn't work well.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Are you asking how to get the routing to work or "make a string with variables" as you stated in the title?  If it is the latter just use the PHP functions $arr = compact($var1, $var2...) and then join(",", $arr) to get your category and gender into comma separated string.

Comment: i want a string, i want that URL is like this http://localhost:8000/shop/t-shirt,men,some-slug-product

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: i tryed like this <img src="<?php
$prefix = compact($product->category->name, $product->gender->name, $product->project->slug);

$output = join(",", $prefix);

?>
                                        
                        > But it doesnt work

Comment: I updated my answer with the correct answer - I should have thought before I typed the response ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace("‐",",",$string);` but having commas in URL it doesnt make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
$prefix = [$product->category->name, $product->gender->name, $product->project->slug];

$output = join(",", $prefix);
```